# Truly centering a floated image

Tags: html, css, image

Basically I've created a site, with image floated to the right.

Like this:

[image: Default]

Everything works nice and clean, only issue comes when it comes to resizing/zooming.

I have modelled my site according to the standards and I don't have any overlapping elements or anything of similar sort.

Basically I've just set my main content to `margin: auto; max-width: 85%;` to generate the page content displaying in middle inside a class, while everything else is displaying on 100% width.

Everything works as expected, even at tablet sizes eg.

[image]

Everything is nicely centered in the middle while the rest of the site stretches out to the edges.

Now, however, when I start exceeding the width limits of the site/picture, issues occur.

Basically,

since my content width is set to 85% the picture begins to squish itself into the left side of my website, in order to mainstain the centering of the right site

Illustration below:

[image]

So I'm asking, is there any good method to prevent this from happening?

I presume the solution will be using @media port and resizing the image, or?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan!

Comment: Depending on which element the image is in, setting `max-width: 100%` might do the trick. For any definitive answer though, we'll need to see (at least a simplified version of) your code.

Comment: @Siguza Thanks, the `max-width: 100%` actually solved it.

Out of curiosity, could you explain in a bit further detail why did it solve the issue? I mean I get that it demands the width to stay consistent, but I've tried using for example overflows to replicate the thought process and it didn't help.

Comment: @Rawrplus There's not much to it, actually. Percentage values are relative to the inherited dimension (which is the one of the parent element if `position` isn't set to `absolute` or `fixed`), and setting that as `max-width` just says "make sure this image is never wider than 100% of the width of its parent", which will make it start shrinking exactly when the parent element becomes as narrow as the image is wide.